# Is radically changing my question that didn't get any answer or votes a good idea?

Tags: discussion, questions

Yesterday I asked a (admittedly vague) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487965/publishing-an-event-at-different-time-intervals-depending-on-condition) about a very specific problem I had, asking for advice about the best way to do something. It got no attention, and since then I've had a good night sleep on top of it, could make progress on it but I'm stumped farther on the path.

Since the initial question has no answer, and is not really focused, I started editing it massively in order to change it to the question I have today. Halfway through though I thought it would be better to ask. So what should I do

- edit on top of the initial question: I don't really like it, it feels like it muddies my intent or the points I was in and am now
- delete and create another question: Perhaps the cleanest way
- edit completely and recycle the question: I'm afraid the question will be hampered by its age and not catch the eye of thoses that could answer.
- leave the question and link to it from another question

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the radical changing of existing questions is frowned upon as this could invalidate any existing answers and make any up-votes less useful.

However in this case where you haven't had a response there are no answers and no up-votes so you could change the question without invalidating anything. In fact you could argue that this is a good thing. Even if the question has a couple of down-votes it would be good to do this. The question will get bumped and if you've made a better question the down-votes countered by up-votes. The only time where this wouldn't work would be where the question's at a score of -3 or lower.

Also bear in mind that questions should be treated as a finite resource and (especially if you're a new user) deleting old questions and creating new ones may well use this resource up and you might find yourself unable to ask any new questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last paragraph correctly; there is an upper limit per user on how many questions one can ask?

Comment: @samy - In theory no, in practice yes. If you ask a number of low quality questions then you will find your ability to ask new questions restricted or even blocked. However, this usually only applies to new users. Someone with a few thousand reputation points shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: @samy [you can find more details here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610/165773) "People that treat questions as a resource that _can_ be depleted, who learn how to ask questions _only_ when they really need to and make them _count_ when they do..."

Comment: Thanks @gnat, that's one big wall of text but very informative :) Anyway, the question was radically edited, I'm in a resource hogging mind :p